# Making Eclipse Variable View window size larger

Tags: eclipse

While debugging in eclipse, I find myself using the move hover over variables for a quick snapshot on a variable, which pops up a quick variable view window. When these are structs, there are many members and the window Eclipse puts showing the data is too small to see more than a couple of them.

Is it possible to change the size of this window to make it larger by default? I constantly have to stop and enlarge it to see everything, which defeats the purpose of using it versus the watch window. I've looked at Eclipse settings and searched in google but no luck.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of hovering the variable, I suggest you to double click the variable (or expression) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, it will bring the *Inspect Variable* popup which you can resize (and it will remember the size the next time you reopen it). Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close it (or click outside the popup).

Is not as simple as hovering over the variable, but the next time you do this combination to a variable (or an expression) the popup will open with the new size.

Comment: I think this answer should get approved by Gustavo. It helped me a lot actually.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+I sometimes don't works, just deletes the variable for unknown reason... :(